# How to check if a regular expression have exactly two capturing groups?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm making a reusable piece of code. One can specify the regular expression for capturing the `api_key` and `signature` groups, like in the following `Authorization` header:

```
AWS 44CF9590006BF252F707:jZNOcbfWmD/A/f3hSvVzXZjM2HU=
```

The regular expression would be:

```
^AWS (?<api_key>.+):(?<signature>.+)$
```

Of course AWS and the order of the key/signature pair may change (that's why I'm using a regular expression). But **there should be always** an `api_key` capturing group and a `signature` capturing group.

How can I check if these groups are present, using another regular expression?

**EDIT**: based on the answers it seems that I was not good at all at explaining the problem.

The user (of this code) is going to provider the regex (like the one above). I need only to check that the given regex as (at least) two capturing grops (`api_key` and `signature`). I'll then use the regex provided to test against `Authorization` header.

Comment: Could you just accept an API_KEY regex and a SIGNATURE regex and then build your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But how do you know that your new regex tests your regex properly? You might need 20-30 levels of regexes :). How about you just try something simple like:

```
if (strpos($yourRegEx, "(?<api_key>") !== false && strpos($yourRegEx, "(?<signature>") !== false) {
```

This is I guess more fool proof:

```
preg_match("\(\?<api_key>.+?\)", $yourRegEx) && preg_match("\(\?<signature>.+?\)", $yourRegEx)
```

Comment: Can't get what you mean, sorry. I need to simply check the presence of two named capturing groups, is this possible?

Comment: I was just joking about using a regex *on* a regex. In any case, I think both of these solutions would work.

Answer (score 0):

Why not check in PHP like:

```
preg_match('^AWS (?<api_key>.+):(?<signature>.+)$', $value, $matches);

assert(count($matches) === 3); // 0, 1 and 2.
```

Comment: That's not what the OP wants. He literally wants a regex to check ANOTHER regex.

Comment: Also, your regex is syntactically invalid - it's missing delimiters.